# Extension missing when debugging Roslyn analyser in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis

I created a new analyzer project in VS 2019 and debugged by pressing F5; all fine.

Then applied changes and renamed the 3 projects. When hit F5 for debugging, breakpoints for the the new version won’t hit.

Then I browsed the extensions in the debugging VS instance and found the old one, with the old name. Removed that one, closed the instance, finish debugging and hit F5 again.

Now, the debugging instance of VS 2019 doesn’t contain the analyzer I’m trying to debug as an extension, and breakpoints won’t hit.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey dude - I'm also crying my eyes out on debugging those extensions. I kept NOT seeing my changes and it kept reading the old Extension.

I tried to change what you insert after /rootsuffix in the debugging section of your project. I used the EXP, as by Mirosoft, but when I tried changing this to 1 - lo and behold. The old cached extensions disappeared.
But, Extensions are confusing. Dont expect normal behaviour in studio, especially during debugging. Test the end product.

Comment: the number 1, is a random symbol I tried.

Comment: I think what you’re suggesting is to create a new visual studio instance, which seems a bit overkill. If you navigate to your %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ folder, you should see new folders for each instance you created when replacing the suffix ‘Exp’. The official command line is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/createexpinstance-utility?view=vs-2019

Comment: The solution that pointed me in the right direction was at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767249/unable-to-debug-vsix-project